# Windows 10 Insider Preview Expired on Dual Boot Ubuntu Machine

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, multi-boot

I have a dual boot Ubuntu 16.04 / Windows 10 machine. When I found out about Bash on Windows, I decided to try it out. This required that I become a Windows Insider. I did not realize, or forgot, that this was going to expire on me, which it now has. The reason I didn't catch it earlier is because, frankly, I've been using Ubuntu as my main OS, and it allowed me to access all my Windows data. Now that Windows Insider is dead, Ubuntu can't access those files anymore. 
It is my understanding that reinstalling Windows in this scenario will wipe out my Ubuntu OS and it's data, and maybe also the Windows data, I'm not sure about that part, but I can't backup the Windows data as it is now anyway.

The solution I want to ask about is getting rid of Windows and expanding Ubuntu to take the whole drive. Will this save my Windows data? What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: WSL doesn't require you install a Windows Insider preview build. If you let a preview build expire then you will have to reinstall Windows

Comment: @Ramhound Not sure what WSL refers to. I got the Insider right after Bash on Windows came out, and I did indeed 'have to' become an Insider, at least then, if not now. Note I am not asking about reinstalling Windows, but getting rid of it. Thanks.

Comment: So format the partition that contains Windows then repair Grub.  WSL is the feature you enabled to get Bash on Windows.